# import and run excel module .bas with RDCOMClient

Tags: r, excel, vba, rdcomclient

I'm trying to use *RDCOMClient* to import a module to an excel workbook.

```
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
XlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(paste0(root, "test.xlsx"))
xlWbk.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(paste0(root, "macro/Module1.bas"))
```

the last line gives the error:

```
 could not find function "xlWbk.VBProject.VBComponents.Import"
```

I also tried the following:

```
xlApp$Run(paste0(root, "macro/Module1.bas!header"))
xlApp$Modules()$AddFromFile(paste0(root, "macro/Module1.bas"))
```

Both of the above code also did not work.

Can anyone help me import this module? I generate this excel macro with *R*, and it's a real pain to copy and paste them into the excel document and run macro by hand.

edit---------

here is the content of the .bas

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Sub Macro2()
Attribute Macro2.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = " \n14"
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
    Range("I6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "hello"
    Range("I7").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R does not use period qualifiers to access underlying methods. However, periods are allowed in object names. So R is attempting to find a function named `xlWbk.VBProject.VBComponents.Import()`.

While in VBA or VBS, period means accessing properties and attributes, in R you need to adjust with `[[` or `$` qualifiers. Hence, consider adjusting to R semantics:

```r
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(paste0(root, "test.xlsx"))

xlWbk$VBProject()$VBComponents()$Import(paste0(root, "macro/Module1.bas"))
```

---

The counterpart in VBA would be using period qualifiers for methods:

```vb
Public Sub ImportModuleCheck()
On Error Goto ErrHandle
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\Path\To\macro\Module1.bas"

   Msgbox "Module successfully imported!", vbInformation
   Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
   Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
   Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I'm getting an error with no tips as to why it caused an error: ```xlWbk$VBProject()$VBComponents()$Import(paste0(root, "macro/Module1.bas"))
Error: Exception occurred.```

I added info to the op.

Comment: What is the content of *root*? Is the `.bas` file located in sub folder, *macro*? Please note you use upper case `X` in workbook object. I use lower case`x` in `xlWbk` to be consistent with `xlApp`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. root is the path to a folder which contains the root folder, and the file module1 above is in root/marco/. I know the file path is fine because ```readLines(con = paste0(root, "macro/Module1.bas"))``` works. 
I exactly copy paste your code above also, and I keep getting "an exception occurred".

Comment: I just imported the file manually through the editor in excel and it worked there. So the code in the file is good also.

Comment: Hmmm...what version of MS Office are you running? Are you on Windows or Mac? I thought at first it was the `.xlsx` which cannot hold any macros (but `.xlsm` can) was the issue but attempting even that you should be prompted with the background Excel process. How are you running R script? Command line, IDE like RStudio, other?

Comment: Thank you again for helping, I really appretiate it. ```Version - Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013```, I am running code through RStudio. I am on Windows.

Comment: You mean manually in excel? Where in Excel would I put that line? I tried to run it in VBA editor in Excel alt+F11, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: See extension of answer showing the VBA counterpart. Run that macro (adjusting path) and describe if code worked or erred out and if erred out what is the exact message.

Comment: got this error - ```1004 - Programmatic access to visual basic project is not trusted```

Comment: Well there you have it! That should be your issue. [Adjust trust settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/282830/programmatic-access-to-office-vba-project-is-denied) of Excel file or maybe move working directories. In fact, with this error you should not be able to run any VBA macro (i.e., whatever you attempt to import).

Comment: Man, you are the best. Do you know if it is possible to adjust those settings programmatically?

Comment: Glad it finally worked out. There might be an automated way but don't know immediately. Look it up and see.